# Compute GeoId undulation in golang

Tags: c#, go, dll, geolocation

I need to compute for the undulation or geoID of lattitude and longitude using golang but i found this package i think its useful

```
https://github.com/garrettsickles/geolocation
```

implemented it but it gives me incorrect geoid and also i did by using dll which could be comfortable with me but the problem is that there is no easier way to read dll files in golang via unix environment but also found difficult to implement it

```
DLLExport
```

i used this in my dll
and also i want to export it and read in golang
but in windows it could be possible but as golang newbie
i cannot be able to figure out how can i achieve 
reading dll in golang in my unix environment (macos darwin)

```
   public interface IComputeMSL
    {
        // DLL Export from msl result
        [DllExport(HelperStr.GetMSLDLL, CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
        double GetMSLResult(double lat, double lon, double gpsElevation);
        // DLL Export from WSG84
        [DllExport(HelperStr.GetWSG84DLL, CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
        double GetWSG84Result(double gpsElevation, double mslElevation);
    }
```

this is my c# dll reader which keeps the geoid computation correctly

```
   public class ComputeMSL : IComputeMSL
    {
        /* GetMSLResult from the parameter as lat, lon, and gps elevation */
        public double GetMSLResult(double lat, double lon, double gpsElevation) =>
            Helper.GetMSL(Helper.GetGeoID(lat, lon), gpsElevation);

        /* GetWSG84Result from the parameter gpsElevation and mslElevation */
        public double GetWSG84Result(double gpsElevation, double mslElevation) =>
            Helper.ConvertMSLToWSG84(gpsElevation, mslElevation);
    }
```

this is computeMSL which computes the msl result and wsg84 both of them are written in c# and used this package for it

```
GeoidHeightsDotNet
```

if anyone can help me to configure correctly my dll to be able to read in unix and windows environment at the same time or any package that can support the computation of geoID in golang or package that can compute egm86, egm2008 i would appreciate your help.

Comment: There are additional correction factors that are required.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference but would appreciate if someone implemented this in golang or implemented dll in golang with unix, linux and windows supported os.

Comment: Net Library applications rely on Windows dlls and in a unix environment you are missing the windows dlls.  I'm not sure why the standard correction factors due to earth not being truly circular is not already built into the libraries you are using.

Comment: Yeah your right but my last resort is by writing a small microservice to connect to my golang. But i read somehow dll is fine in unix environment. But cross platform support for dll is there but the problem is in golang how to read the windows dll or dll file.

Comment: What are you getting for the accuracy?  See : https://developer.here.com/blog/tracking-device-location-with-golang-wlan-access-points-and-the-here-positioning-api

Comment: Am getting for the elevation of the drone which i found only supported by c# or c which is dificult for me to readl dll in golang, also i need the accuracy of geoid for mean sea level

Comment: Early GPS receivers has issues with latitude and most receivers were fixed around 10-15 years ago.  Not sure why unix applications were not fixed.  Drones are pretty new so I would think their receiver are accurate.  What happens if you compare you cell phone location with the drone location.  I want to find out if the issue is with the drone or the issue with you PC.  Using a cell phone will tell which is wrong.

Comment: Supposedly in windows environment supported the location stuff but on unix i cannot find any cross platform for dll.